# proving algebraically that the space of smooth vectorial fields over a smooth manifold is infinite dimensional

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension m and $X:M \rightarrow TM$ a smooth vectorial field. I want to prove that the set of all smooth vectorial fields is infinite dimensional algebraic. I know that it can be proved by seeing it as a $C^{\infty}(M)$ module.

Comment: Can you please say what you mean by "finding a basis"? For example, on the two-sphere, can you describe what you would consider to be a basis (as opposed to "an infinite linearly-independent set of vector fields")?

Comment: I suggest you start by proving that the space, $\mathcal{F}_{n,U}$, of smooth functions $f:U\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is infinite-dimensional (where $n\geq 1$ and $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is open)… for which it suffices to consider $n=1$. Then, show there is an isomorphic copy of $\mathcal{F}_{n,U}$ sitting inside the space of all smooth vector fields fields on $M$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo    I can handle the first part of proof, but I don't know how to prove that there is an isomorphic copy of $F_{n,U}$
 sitting inside the space of all smooth vector fields fields on M.
.